# Does anyone have a working Jenkins agent configuration for git clone on z/OS R2.4

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, mvs

I am trying to use the GitSCM Jenkins plugin on z/OS R2.4 with Rocket's git implementation. The agent configuration that worked on R2.3 no longer works on R2.4 because the `utf8` encoding no longer works - so the IBM documentation also is fairly out of date on this. We had to move to `-Dfile.encoding=ISO8859-1` just to run commands on the system successfully - otherwise nothing.

However, when trying to use git checkout via SSH, I get public key authentication errors getting to the remote upstream. This also happens when we use the SSH Agent plugin. When attempting this outside Jenkins everything seems fine whether using an agent or directly with git. We have a valid `~/.ssh/config` file on the agent that works for our Jenkins user from a command line as does `ssh-agent`. The `git-jenkins.sh` script to use instead of git directly, which IBM suggests using, simply does not work even after fixing the obvious scripting errors. I am suspicious that the SSH key/passphrase is not being encoded correctly for SSH communication but cannot prove that is causing the problem.

Does anyone have a working configuration on z/OS R2.4? We did not have encoding issues on R2.3 but cannot rollback and did not work with the GitSCM plugin back then anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, for testing, try with an SSH key without passphrase, in order to confirm is the issue is related to said passphrase or not.

Second, check the  R2.4 ServerPack for SSH and the OpenSSH_x version r(compared to R2.3): that can give some clues as to what has changed between the two versions, and why SSH (which was working before) no longer work.

Comment: Using SSH-AGENT and then git commands from shell within the SSH-Agent pipeline context in Jenkins works fine. It is only when the GitSCM plugin is involved that this fails. Looks like the private key is not being encoded correctly when sent to the upstream when GitSCM supplies credentials. We're working on figuring out where the gap in and suspect it is in IBM's git-jenkins.sh script. More to come when we figure this out.